# Duplicate identifier 'EnumMeasureTypes'.ts(2300)

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, ngrx-store, facade

I need to pass values to this function

measures.facade.ts

```
loadModulesMeasures(modules: [Module, EnumMeasureTypes[]][], scale: EnumApiScales, timeRange: TimeRange)
```

So, I have tried to store values in each variable and thought of passing only those values as parameters.

home.component.ts

```
1. const m = this.modulesFacade.currentHomeModules$
2. enum e {EnumMeasureTypes.TEMPERATURE, EnumMeasureTypes.HUMIDITY, EnumMeasureTypes.PRESSURE}
3. this.measuresFacade.loadModulesMeasures([m,e][],...)
```

measures.interface.ts

```
export const MeasureTypes =  [
EnumMeasureTypes.TEMPERATURE,
EnumMeasureTypes.PRESSURE,
EnumMeasureTypes.HUMIDITY,]

export interface RawModuleMeasures {
  id: string;
  measures: RawMeasuresBatch[];
  measureTypes?: EnumMeasureTypes[],
}
```

I get duplicate identifier for EnumMeasureTypes on line 2.

Comment: This syntax is not valid for creating enums. Do it like this: `enum EnumMeasureTypes { TEMPERATURE, HUMIDITY, PRESSURE }`

Comment: okay. So I can pass EnumMeasureTypes as the parameter?

Comment: You can, but it probably will not behave as you expect. What will the method `this.measuresFacade.loadModulesMeasures` do with the enum?

Comment: It will dispatch the following    

this.dispatch(LoadModulesMeasures({
      home: {
        id: modules[0][0].homeId,
        modules: modules.map(([m, measureTypes]) => {
          return {id: m.id, bridge: m.bridge, type: this.combineMeasureTypes(measureTypes).join(',')};
        }),
      },
      scale,
      timeRange,
      correlation_id,
    })